# Using a MySQL select query to generate a report

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. I need to produce two quick reports on the number of logins per user per day and the number of logins per user per IP address. How can I generate these reports?

```
Users
----
user_id
username

UserLoginLog
----
log_id
user_id
logdate
ipaddr
```

Comment: Do you know how to write queries?

Comment: If you have a query you are working on and stuggling with, we're happy to take a look; but we can't just write the query for you.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you're looking for is `group by` - it allows you to break a dataset up to groups, and run an aggregate function on each of them.

Logins per day:

```
SELECT   DATE(logdate), COUNT(*)
FROM     UserLoginLog
GROUP BY DATE(logdate)
```

Logins per user per IP address:

```
SELECT   user_id, ip_addr, COUNT(*)
FROM     UserLoginLog
GROUP BY user_id, ip_addr
```